# Entity Framework Nested Table Relation SelectMany

Tags: entity-framework

My problem is the following query return zero records.But there are records in the database.

My aim SubjectQuestion Select the table by Subjectid get that equal questionmodel.

How can I do. Help you Thank you.

[My Models]

> **SubjectQuestion**

```
public  class SubjectQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Question.Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public QuestionModel ToModel()
   {
       return new QuestionModel(Id,QuestionNo,Title,Description,ChoiceId);
   }    
}
```

**QuestionModel**

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    public QuestionModel(int id, int questionNo, string title, string description,int choiceid)
    {
        Id = id;
        QuestionNo = questionNo;
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        ChoiceId = choiceid;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNo { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } 
}
```

**Entity Framework Query**

```
List<QuestionModel> lst = _db.SubjectQuestions.Where(x => x.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList().SelectMany(r=> r.Question.Select(y=> y.ToModel()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

> SubjectQuestion

```
public  class SubjectQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question.Question Question { get; set; } //Change one to one
}

list = _db.QuestionSubjects.Where(i => i.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList().Select(x => x.Questions.ToModel()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here

```
_db.SubjectQuestions.Where(x =>
  x.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList()
```

At this point you are executing the query just against SubjectQuestions, so EF only brings across that table and not the List of Questions. If you use an Include statement for the questions, that should fix it.

```
_db.SubjectQuestions.Include(x => x.Questions).Where(x =>
  x.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList()
```

Addtionally, if it was me, I make the relationship with SubjectQuestions explicit on your Questions class (by including a SubjectQuestion property and probably an Id). Then the query would simply be

```
_db.Questions.Where(x =>
  x.SubjectQuestion.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList().Select(y=> y.ToModel())
```

Comment: Results also returns zero records . :( You can be connected to my computer?

Comment: If you seperate ou the query, as in var result = _db.SubjectQuestions.Where(x =>
  x.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList(); What does the debugger tell you about result, do the subquestions have any questions attached? It could be that although there is data in the database, the model isn't picking up the relationship correctly

Comment: var result = _db.SubjectQuestions.Where(x => x.SubjectId == subjectId).ToList();   Result = 22 Count